# How to increase LimitRequestFieldSize in shared hosting (via .htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

I have tried to update this value by adding `LimitRequestFieldSize 16380` on the first line but it throws `Internal Server Error`. Could anyone suggest if it is possible to achieve.

Comment: We're not able to support shared web hosting here. You should contact your web hosting provider for assistance with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `LimitRequestFieldSize` in `.htaccess` (hence the "Internal Server Error"). As noted in the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize), this can only be set in a server config or virtual host context.

Unless your *shared host* gives you specific access to change this setting (which I doubt) or allows you to modify the `<VirtualHost>` (unlikely) then you can't change this setting.

You'll need to contact your hosting provider.